# I'm building a student list out of a double LL

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to build a list of students using my double linked list class. I ended up combining my student and Node class together to do this. I realize there are better ways to implement this, but this is the path I chose and i'm trying to get it to work. When I push_back a node (Student), it calls my Node class, which then calls my Record class which then calls my Course class.

When calling my constructor for a node in my main function, i'm hit with the error that none of the strings I pass "(Name, course, semester) was not declared in this scope". I realize this might be a mess, but can anyone give me an idea as to why this isn't working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"
using namespace std;



int main () {

    LinkedList* list = new LinkedList();

    list->push_back(John, Math34, Summer2012);

    return 0;
}
```

My LinkedList class. I took out most of the functions so it will be easier to read and find the root of the problem.

```
#ifndef LinkedList_H
#define LinkedList_H
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class LinkedList{

public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        front = NULL;
        back = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    void aCourse(string n, Course* c, string s)
    {  
        if (front == NULL)
        return;
        Node *temp = front;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(n == temp->name)
            front->addCourse(c, s);

    }       }
    void push_back(string n, Course* c, string s)
    {
        if (back == NULL)
        {
            back = new Node(NULL, NULL, n);
            front = back;
            size++;
            back->addCourse(c, s);
            return; 
        }
        else {

            Node *newnode = new Node(NULL, NULL, n);
            newnode->addCourse(c, s);
            back->next = newnode;
            newnode->prev = back;
            back = newnode;


    }
#endif
```

My Node / Student class:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include "Record.h"
#include "Course.h"
class Node
{
public:
    Node(Node* n = NULL, Node* p = NULL, string v = NULL)
    {   
        prev =  p;
        next = n;
        name = v;
        rec = new Record;
    }

    void addCourse(Course* c, string sem)
    {
        rec->addCourse(c, sem);
    }

    void dropCourse(Course* c)
    {
        rec->dropCourse(c);
    }

    Record* getRecord() { return rec; } 
    void printAllRecords()
    {
        rec->print();
    }

    void setStudentScore(Course* c, int score)
    {
        rec->setCourseScore(c, score);

    }

    string name;
    Record* rec;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev; //for double linked list
    char value;
};
#endif
```

My record class:

```
#ifndef Record_H
#define Record_H
#include "Course.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Record
{
public:
    Record()
    {
        courses = new vector<Course*>();
        semesters = new vector<string>();
        scores = new vector<int>();
    }
    ~Record()
    {
        delete courses;
        delete semesters;
        delete scores;
    }
    void addCourse(Course* c, string sem)
    {
        courses->push_back(c);
        semesters->push_back(sem);
        scores->push_back(0);

    }

    void dropCourse(Course* c)
    {
        vector<Course*>::iterator it = courses->begin();
        vector<string>::iterator it2 = semesters->begin();
        while ( it != courses->end() && it2 != semesters->end())
        {
            if (c == *it)
                break;
            it++;
            it2++;
        }
        courses->erase(it);
        semesters->erase(it2);
    }

    void setCourseScore(Course* c, int g)
    {
        vector<Course*>::iterator it = courses->begin();
        vector<int>::iterator it2 = scores->begin();
        while ( it != courses->end() && it2 != scores->end())
        {
            if (c == *it)
                break;
            it++;
            it2++;
        }

        it2 = scores->insert(it2, g);
    }
    void computeAccGPA()
    {

    }

    vector<Course*>* getCourses() { return courses; } 
    void print(){
        vector<Course*>::iterator it = courses->begin();
        vector<string>::iterator it2 = semesters->begin();
        vector<int>::iterator it3 = scores->begin();
        while ( it != courses->end() && it2 != semesters->end() && it3 != scores->end())
        {
            (*it)->print();
            cout<<" "<<*it2<<" "<<*it3<<endl;
            it++;
            it2++;
            it3++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
private:
    vector<Course*>* courses;
    vector<string>* semesters;
    vector<int>* scores;
};
#endif
```

My course class:

```
#ifndef Course_H
#define Course_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Course
{
public:
    Course(string n, string f, int c)
    {
        name = n;
        faculty = f;
        credit =c;
    }
    ~Course() {}

    void print()
    {
        cout<<name<<" "<<faculty<<" ";//<<c<<" ";
    }
private:
    string name;
    string faculty;
    int credit;
};
#endif
```

Comment: That is a lot of code - any chance of reduce it a bit to expose the error?

Comment: Make a [testcase](http://sscce.org)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a student class double Linked List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725607/building-a-student-class-double-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

I think this line `list->push_back(John, Math34, Summer2012);` is the problem.

You are not passing strings. Replace it with `list->push_back("John", new Course("Math (course name)", "Math (faculty)", 34), "Summer2012");`

Comment: If I do that I get the error "void Linkedlist::push_back(std::string, Course*, std::string) no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const chat[7] to 'course*'

Comment: Sure... you need to call the constructor of Course.

Comment: I'd call the constructor inside the constructor?

Comment: I call the constructor inside my push_back function in my LinkedList class

Comment: Now it should work. Or at least you should get enough hints out of it to get it to work ;)

Comment: I still can't figure out how to call the constructor for Course. Nothing seems to be working